# How to make a pixel perfect circle?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, pixel-art

currently I'm using AI for creating icons. However, When I tried using a 1-pixel border for my circle. the arc side is pixelated can you show me how to make it pixel perfect? Thanks

Please see the below image. As you can see it's pixelated but in using a line it's fine?
[image]

Comment: it's pixelated cause it's on Pixel Preview

Comment: If you want to control the anti-aliasing, either turn it off in AI preferences or use an application better designed for pixel art, i.e. a *raster* application. Illustrator isn't a great tool for pixel art.

Comment: thanks for the infor Scott, can I know what the best application to create a pixel perfect icons? Thanks

Comment: Any raster app will work, from Photoshop to Gimp to Krita ..